# Expo-AV React Native Delayed speech while recording

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

Is it possible to use expo-av in RN project and make it so that there is a voice recording and you can immediately hear your own voice with a delay?
At this moment I only get to hear my voice after pressing the Stop recording button, as it specified in the documentation.
I need to make something like DAF(Delayed Auditory Feedback) example:*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SB9soPELLVc*